# Testing Firefox Add-on/Extension Internationalization

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I have created a Firefox Add-on using `jpm` and I have added a number of localization files such as:

- locale/da.properties
- locale/en-GB.properties
- locale/en-US.properties
- locale/fi.properties

And so on...

In my HTML files I use attributes to set these values, for example: `data-l10n-id="ext_panel_heading_text"`.

I know the translations are working, because changes I make to values in `en-GB.properties` are reflected in my add-ons HTML page.

I've tried navigating to `Options > Content > Choose... (under languages)`, removing English and adding another language (such as Finnish), however it doesn't seem to have an affect on the `.properties` file loaded by my extension. I also tried restarting Firefox after changing the language.

My question is: How do I test the different languages?

Answer (score 0):

The language of Firefox is dependent on the activated language pack, or for Windows and Mac I believe it is hard coded into the build.

Language packs are available from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to change `general.useragent.locale` to the locale you want to use (`en-GB`, `da`, `en-US`, `fi`) in `about:config`and then **restarting your browser**: that way your add-on should show localized texts.

As an alternative, you can use [Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/), which does the same but it's a little more friendly.